# Print true if the integer has a duplicate, otherwise false

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to write a program that asks for the list length and its integer elements. From the integer list though, the program needs to find out of there is a duplicate integer and if there is one: print "True" if a duplicate is found, other wise false.

This should be the sample output:

```
Enter list length: 3
Enter element 1: 100
Enter element 2: 2312
Enter element 3: 12312312
Has duplicate?: False


emp = [] 
listLen = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
num = 1

for i in range(listLen):
  e = int(input("Enter element %d: " % num))
  num += 1
```

(this part ^ is just for the asking inputs)

```
for i in range(e):
  if e.count(item) > 1:
    print("Has duplicate?: True")
  else:
    print("Has duplicate?: False")
```

I keep getting an error though:

```
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-7-d4356802d6f7> in <module> 8 9 for i in range(e): ---> 10 if e.count(item) > 1: 11 print("Has duplicate? True") 12 else: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'count' –
```

Comment: `I keep getting an error`: What is the error? Post the whole error message with full traceback.

Comment: When people ask for more details, remember that those details [go in your post](/help/how-to-ask). The idea is to get your to put all the details in your post so that someone can just read that, and have all the information to help you, without needing to read through the comment thread. (The better the post, the fewer comments are necessary before someone writes an answer).

Comment: Please add what error you are getting.

Comment: Note that `i` and `item` are not the same.  The easy way to detect duplicates is to do `if len(set(e)) == len(e):`.

Comment: Also note that `e` is simply an integer and not a list...

Answer (score 1):

when you apply `count` function it should be like `list_name.count(the_value_to_count)`

but when you are doing `e.count(item)` e is basically a number not a **list,set,tuple**..

you can apply count function like this.

```
emp = [] 
listLen = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
num = 1

for i in range(listLen):
  e = int(input("Enter element %d: " % num))
  num += 1
  emp.append(e)
  

for i in set(emp):
  #emp is a list. and i is the number. for which we have to count.    
  if emp.count(i) > 1:
    print(str(i)+" Has duplicate?: True")
  else:
    print(str(i)+" Has duplicate?: False")
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the number of elements: 6
Enter element 1: 99
Enter element 2: 42
Enter element 3: 63
Enter element 4: 42
Enter element 5: 56
Enter element 6: 99
56 Has duplicate?: False
42 Has duplicate?: True
99 Has duplicate?: True
63 Has duplicate?: False
```

**Note** the `list` is not in order as i have applied **set** in for loop

**Updated answer.**

**If you just wanted to check if list contains duplicate or not.**

Using **counter**

```
from collections import Counter
emp = [] 
listLen = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
num = 1

for i in range(listLen):
  e = int(input("Enter element %d: " % num))
  num += 1
  emp.append(e)
  
a=Counter(emp)
if max(a.values()) > 1:
    print(" List Has duplicate?: True")
else:
    print(" List Has duplicate?: False")
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the number of elements: 5
Enter element 1: 2
Enter element 2: 3
Enter element 3: 1
Enter element 4: 2
Enter element 5: 5
List Has duplicate?: True
```